# two sphere collision, distribution of KE

Tags: forces, energy, collision

If we have two glass balls of exact same mass and size. We tape to the first one a very little piece of titanium facing the other sphere and we collide the two spheres at the same speed. The question is: will the titanium little piece be hit by the entire KE of the two spheres.

My friend says since the impact point of the spheres will be on that piece of titanium it will be hit from front and back by the two spheres thus receive the entire KE of the two spheres.

What I think is since the titanium piece is much stronger then the glass, when it gets hit it will break the glass and sink inside one of the spheres, thus the two spheres will collide with each other transferring their KE on each other instead of the little piece. What I say is the little piece will only receive enough KE to break through the glass, the rest of the KE will be between the two spheres stopping each others movement.

So who is right?

Comment: Yes the pint of application of force is at the point of contact. We don't bother about it breaks afterwards or not. And in the situation in the diagram the force on all points will be the same, if the surface of contact is smooth

Comment: the answer will probably be easier if the balls just deform instead of breaking it, as in the last case the forces change with the chaotic nature of the break

Comment: @brucesmitherson I changed the question to a simpler one.